# Xamarin UWP access denied to local storage

Tags: xamarin, uwp, local-storage, access-denied

In my manifest i activated access to storage and access in my localstorage is always denied when 2 or more folders :

```
_packageName_\LocalState\<HERE>  is ok
_packageName_\LocalState\folder1\<HERE>  is ok
_packageName_\LocalState\folder1\folder2\<HERE>  is denied
```

I don't know why i can access to my OWN localstorage when more than 2 folders... And it works when less !

NOTE : Access is denied only when i want to read files, i can create folders and file anywhere in my local storage

Comment: What do you mean by `activated access` in the manifest file? Could you please tell me how did you do that?  Also, which did you use to access the foloder?

Comment: I add capabilities to external storage and broad file system access. It is supposed to give me access to more than my own storage but it seem not change anything

Comment: What is the external storage capabiity? And what is the API that you used to access these folders?

Comment: It is supposed to grant access to an eventual sd card where some needed files can be. I use a sared folder (my local storage) to get and post files and folders via a NetExplorer account

Comment: Please share the code that you used to access the folder.

Comment: I just used this : 
System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"{rootFolder.Path}\\10.json". In the error message, the path is good (iget the rootFolder with PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage)

Comment: broad file system capability only works for the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage?view=winrt-22000) APIs. You need to use StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync to get the folder.

Comment: But i can t add the reference because adding this reference may cause a circular dependency. I don't know how but because of this i can't

Comment: Any updates about this issue? Have you tried the DependencyService that I mentioned?

Comment: No update, sometime it works sometime not

Comment: This is the last app i write with Xamarin, it's too unstable and have too many problems

Comment: Do you mean the DependencyService will still give you this error?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin UWP apps, you could not directly use [Windows.Storage APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage?view=winrt-22000). The solution for your scenario is that you should create a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in your project. The **DependencyService** class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code. So in this way, you could call the native UWP Windows.Storage APIs and get the file that you want for your app.